# continue jQuery after mysql data has loaded

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I am using jquery and php along with WordPress to access data from a mysql database.

I managed to retrieve that data but would like jquery to wait until all the data has been retrieved.

Below is the pertinent code segment.

Both alert commands display nothing because the data has not finished loading.

How can I re-code this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    load_qs('foo');
    alert($(".all-qa-free").val());
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function load_qs(data) {
        var data = {
            action: 'load_question_set',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            qset_id: data
        };

        $.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
            var mydb_data = $.parseJSON(response);
            $("#all-qa").val(mydb_data.qa);
            alert($(".all-qa-free").val());
            return;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are asynchronous, while the JS executes synchronously. jQuery/JavaScript initiates the ajax calls and immediately goes to the next line for executing. It doesn't wait for the response to come from the server.

Solution:
Do all the processing, which you want to do on server response in the callback function itself. In your case, in the below function:

```
function(response) {         
    var mydb_data = $.parseJSON(response);
    $("#all-qa").val(mydb_data.qa);
  alert ($(".all-qa-free").val());  
    return; 
}
```

Otherwise you will keep facing this issue. Try putting alert in the callback function. It'll definitely work.

One more thing, you are putting value in id "#all-qa" and fetching data from ".all-qa-free", please check if you are doing this right.

--
HappyCoding

Answer (score 0):

You should set `async: true`  in your ajax call.

Setting async to false means that the statement you are calling has to complete before the next statement in your function can be called.
 If you set async: true then that statement will begin it's execution and  next statement will be called regardless of whether the async statement has completed yet.

Comment: Thanks, I set async :true  but unfortunately  I get the same result.

Comment: make sure that  $(".all-qa-free")  had value .  just comment load_qs('foo'); and check.

Comment: It dos have a value. For this post I removed the unnecessary stuff.   My actual code used $("#all-qa").val(game_data.qa);  then a bit later:  alert ($("#all-qa").val());  which displays nothing. The html textbox displays the expected content.

Comment: make sure the ajax return the value  . add  alert(mydb_data.qa)  ;  after the line var mydb_data = $.parseJSON(response);